# Scroll when dragging an draggable item

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Im currently developing a drag n' drop plugin.

Im trying to create the 'scroll' feature like on jquery draggable.

Im currently trying:

```
$('.drag').bind('drag', function(event) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var offT = $t.offset().top;
    var offL = $t.offset().left;
    var doch = $(document).height() - screen.height;
    $('b').html(offT + '<' + (screen.height - $t.height() * 2 - $t.height() / 2));
    if (offT < screen.height - $t.height() * 2 - $t.height() / 2) {
        $(this).css({
            top: event.offsetY,
            left: event.offsetX
        });
        $('body').scrollTop(event.offsetY - offT - screen.height + 1000);
    }
    else if (offT > screen.height - $t.height() * 2 - $t.height() / 2) {
        $(this).css({
            top: event.offsetY,
            left: event.offsetX
        });
        $('body').scrollTop(event.offsetY - offT + screen.height + 1000);
    }
    else {

        $(this).css({
            top: event.offsetY,
            left: event.offsetX
        });

    }
});
```

I hope it isn't to confusing. Well you can see it doesn't work very well:
http://jsfiddle.net/vJvEV/34/show/

I really didn't know how to do it so I was clue less. Does anyone have a better way to scroll when the draggable element gets to far to the end of the viewable part of the screen?